# Python SSO for TWiki, Bugzilla and SuiteCRM

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, single-sign-on

I'm writing a SSO web app in Python 3.7 for our TWiki, Bugzilla and SuiteCRM internal sites. All 3 sites are using LDAP for authentication and I can authenticate directly with all 3 sites via Firefox and Chrome using the same credentials set in LDAP.

In Python, I'm able to authenticate with all 3 sites using the Requests library and pass the cookies back to the browser. However, only TWiki and Bugzilla accept the cookies passed to the browser from my Python script. SuiteCRM says my session has expired and requires log in. I know authentication succeeded because the cookies are passed to the browser from the WSGI script when using the correct credentials and they are absent when using the wrong credentials.

All three sites are under the same dev.domain.com domain and the Python script runs under the same dev.domain.com domain.

The server is using the WSGI Apache module. The script authenticates using the requests lib, saves the cookies as a dict in a variable and appends the dict to the response header before returning the response to the browser. I'm using SuiteCRM version 7.8.20, Python 3.7 and Apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7.5. SeLinux is running in permissive mode. I have a static web login page that simply sends the authentication credentials to the sso.py script:

login.html

```
    <form action="https://dev.domain.com/sso" class="login-form" method="post">
      <input name=username type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input name=password type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
    </form>
```

sso.py

```
import requests 
import Cookie
...

def auth(url,auth_params,custom_headers):
    try:
        headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
        headers.update(custom_headers)
        session = requests.session()
        response = session.get(url,headers=headers,params=auth_params,verify=False)
        response = session.post(url,headers=headers,params=auth_params,verify=False)
        cookies = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(response.cookies)
        return cookies
    except:
        return "failed auth"

# authenticate and save auth cookies 
    bz_cookies = auth(bz_url,bz_auth_params,bz_custom_headers)
    twiki_cookies = auth(twiki_url,twiki_auth_params,twiki_custom_headers)
    sugar_cookies = auth(sugar_url,sugar_auth_params,sugar_custom_headers)

...

# iteritems to add bugzilla cookies to response
    try:
        for key, value in bz_cookies.iteritems():
            cookie = key + "=" + value
            response_headers.append(('Set-Cookie',cookie))
    except:
        output = bytes("no bz_cookie")

## iteritems to add twiki cookies to response
    try:
        for key, value in twiki_cookies.iteritems():
            cookie = key + "=" + value

            response_headers.append(('Set-Cookie',cookie))

    except:
        output = bytes("no twiki cookie")

## iteritems to add sugarcrm cookies to response
    try:
        for key, value in sugar_cookies.iteritems():
            cookie = key + "=" + value

            response_headers.append(('Set-Cookie',cookie))

    except:
        output = bytes("no sugar cookie")

...


    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [bytes(output),response_headers]
```

I can include more detail if needed but this is the basic approach I'm taking to build an internal SSO for our web apps.

If anyone has any idea what I should check please let me know. I've searched the web for SSO help but everything I find is mostly unrelated to my set up.

Is there a better way to pass authentication tokens to the browser or is this the only way to tie these sites together under one roof?

Am I re-inventing the wheel here?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This works when using PHP, I can authenticate with all three web applications, pass the authentication cookies to the browser. Loading the individual sites after this process will result in being automatically authenticated. I don't know why it's not working with Python.